# Node modules folder gets corrupted and requires everytime I restart the computer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, node-modules

I have my nodejs projects on my google drive folder.. When I starts a project it works fine.. but when I restart the computer and run the project again, an error of `cannot find module ...` happens , every time different module is missing.
Running `npm install` doesn't help, only deleting the whole node_modules folder and reinstalling it works but the same will happen after I restart my computer.
Any help or suggestion ?

Comment: When you say it is on your google drive folder, do you mean that you are syncing your entire node_modules folder?

Comment: I would not recommend keeping your libraries like that on your google drive.  It's probably trying to keep all those files and sync and choking.

Comment: Sounds pretty localized to me.  I thought that was what source control was for?  What am I missing here?

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Source control should be for non-ephemeral files.  Libraries should be able to be blown away and re-obtained at any time.  Keeping your dependencies under your source control will bloat your tree and mean that any updates will force a commit to your dependency metadata (package.json) **as well as** your copy of library itself which should be maintained in that libraries repository.

Comment: @JoeLissner yes exactly

Comment: you aren't supposed to source control the node_modules folder itself, that's why you need to have an accuralte package.json file so that each time you run `npm install`, it installs the correct stuff. The issue with node_modules is that it can create an absurd amount of directories (to the point where i once tried to manually delete a single file that was **WAAAAAAAAAAAAY** deep and windows gave me an error saying file path was too long). So I would be the google folder has a max depth when syncing. If you need to do it this way though, `npm install --force` each time should do it though.

Comment: I see I should have clarified with my somewhat flippant comment i.e. keeping a remote copy of stuff vs a local copy i.e. the "project" files seem to be unique to a solution related to the specific domain.  I DO know what source control is.